# How to get Golden Shovel?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I don't know how to get a Golden Shovel in Animal Crossing New Leaf.
If you know how, please tell me I'll be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You get a golden shovel by purchasing 50 bags of fertilizer at the garden area. To find the fertilizer at the garden shop, you must upgrade Timmy and Tommy's Store to it's final upgrade. To do that, you must spend 100,000 bells at the T&T Store.

Answer (score 0):

To get the golden shovel you must purchase 50 bags of fertilizer from the garden shop. It's only available if you have upgraded it to the department store.

Comment: Could you vote up my answer and mark is as correct then we can both get rep and glad I could help